# SiteCatalyst Exit Links with "#" href

Tags: javascript, tags, web-analytics, adobe-analytics

I'm struggling to understand how to stop some automatic Exit Links tracking, due to the *trackExternalLinks=true* option in the s_code library.
These links have just the "**#**" href attribute and every click upon them is firing the automatic Exit Link tracking request.
My obvious thought was to include the "#" string in the **InternalFilters** property, but it does not work, maybe because it's not a real domain.
Any hint before trying to hardcode a workaround like returning false everything except their href ??
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `#` to `linkInternalFilters` is the right way to go.

**Check the following:**

- In your post, you called it `InternalFilters`.  You may have just typoed it here, but to be clear, the correct variable is [`linkInternalFilters`](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/linkInternalFilters.html)
- Make sure `linkInternalFilters` isn't getting overwritten by some other instance of it. It is very common for this variable to be set in multiple places, particularly with implementations spanning multiple sites that may each have their own local/site configuration.
- Make sure `#` is not in [`linkExternalFilters`](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/linkExternalFilters.html).
- If you are using the `exitLinkHandler` or `linkHandler` plugins, make sure you there's no logic in your use of them that is counting it as an exit link (e.g. specifying it as an arg for something to match against)

***Update:*** Adding comment that actually solved the issue.

- In principle, this is same as point #2 above:  If you are implementing this as a tool in DTM, then in the tool config, you will need to go to **Link Tracking > Outbound Links** and add `#` to **Never Track**. This is what DTM uses to pop `linkInternalFilters` and in most cases it will overwrite the `linkInternalFilters` you set yourself

Comment: Thanks @Crayon but none of your suggestions are valid in my case :( I'm still getting deep into it (this an AppMeasurement library)

Comment: @Rik Okay well.. these still apply.. are you by chance implementing this as a tool in DTM? If so, in the tool config, you will need to go to **Link Tracking > Outbound Links** and add `#` to **Never Track**.  This is what DTM uses to pop `linkInternalFilters` and in most cases it will overwrite the `linkInternalFilters` you set yourself

Comment: @Rik if that is n/a to you too, then.. tbh i really don't know what else it could be. I'm pretty sure it *must* be one of the above, particularly point #2

Comment: I investigated a possible override of the linkInternalFilters var but it's not the case. Anyway, I'm using the library with the DTM and I'm gonna try the Outbound option you said

Comment: Nice @Crayon! Migrating the linkInternalFilters (and the other In/Out bound options) from the library to the DTM solved any matters like the "#" one. I had those properties set both, and differently, in the library and DTM and this fired a conflict I suppose. Thx !